# Sending images twice to CouchDb instead of 1 time

Tags: python, django, couchdb, zip

I try to send zip file which is unpacked in memory and images are sent to database. But images are sent twice and I don't know where the problem is. Can someone tell please?

```
def uploadZIP(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      mosaic = 'C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/myimages.zip'
      zip_name = ZipFile(mosaic)
      db_view = launch_db.view('_all_docs', include_docs=True)
      list_of_files = [name for name in zip_name.namelist()] 
      imageNumber = len(list_of_files) 
      imgInDBNumber = len(db_view) 
      if imageNumber != 0:
            generalImageNumber = imgInDBNumber - 1
            for j in range(imageNumber):
                for i in range(0, len(list_of_files)):
                    archive = ZipFile(mosaic, 'r')
                    image = archive.read(list_of_files[i])
                    image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
                    file_name = 'img{0}'.format(generalImageNumber)
                    rgb, img = rgbValue(image, file_name)
                    generalImageNumber = generalImageNumber + 1
                    launch_db.save(rgb)
                    launch_db.put_attachment(rgb, img, 'image.png', 'image/png')
                    launch_db.commit()
      messages.info(request, 'ZIP file with images was successfully sent')
    return render(request, 'add_images.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,I found,the problem was in

```
for i in range(0, len(list_of_files))
```

i had to write

```
for i in range(1, len(list_of_files))
```